# Slim/Middleman conditional for layout based on active page

Tags: ruby, slim-lang, middleman

I'm a ruby novice. I've been using Middleman and Slim for a static site. I'd like to create conditional comments in my layout that only render certain images or include certain javascript files based on the active page.

So something like

```
if page title is "foo"
   render image of a cat
else
   render image of a dog
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, using actual code, not just pseudocode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Middleman, but I would accomplish this by setting a variable in the markup for the page and then use that variable in the layout markup.

Ex.

Page Markup

`- @page_title = 'foo'`

Layout Markup

`- if @page_title == "foo"
  / something
- else
  / something else`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using Middleman's local page data helper, assuming you've set page title in Frontmatter.

```
    <% if current_page.data.title.eql?("foo") %>
        <span>Shown if True</span>
    <% else %>
        <span>Shown if False</span>
    <% end %>
```

You can also use data.url or data.path if you don't want to rely on title.